# Filter users using by two different user meta

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I have a user meta field called country (string) and another one called is_blocked (binary). What I need is returns the number of non-blocked users per country selecting the user registered date too.

With this query, I managed to get the values without considering the is_blocked field:

```
SELECT meta_value AS 'country', COUNT(meta_value) AS 'total'
FROM wp_usermeta INNER JOIN
     wp_users
     ON wp_usermeta.user_id = wp_users.ID
WHERE meta_key = 'user_country' AND
      meta_value <> '' AND 
      DATE_FORMAT(wp_users.user_registered, '%Y-%m') = '2021-01'
GROUP BY meta_value
ORDER BY total DESC
```

But I can't just select only non-bloked users. What I try:

```
SELECT meta_value AS 'country', COUNT(meta_value) AS 'total'
FROM wp_usermeta INNER JOIN
     wp_users
     ON wp_usermeta.user_id = wp_users.ID
WHERE meta_key = 'user_country' AND
      meta_value <> '' AND 
      DATE_FORMAT(wp_users.user_registered, '%Y-%m') = '2021-01' AND
     (wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'user_blocked' AND
      CAST(wp_usermeta.meta_value AS BINARY) != '1'
     )
GROUP BY meta_value
ORDER BY total DESC
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Define "blocked user".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another `join` or exists:

```
SELECT umc.meta_value AS country, COUNT(umb.user_id) AS total
FROM wp_users u INNER JOIN
     wp_usermeta umc
     ON umc.user_id = u.ID AND
        umc.meta_key = 'user_country' AND
        umc.meta_value <> '' LEFT JOIN
     wp_usermeta umb
     ON umb.user_id = u.ID AND
        umb.meta_key = 'user_blocked' AND
        CAST(umb.meta_value AS BINARY) <> '1'
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(u.user_registered, '%Y-%m') = '2021-01'
GROUP BY umc.meta_value
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

This should give you `0` values, if you have countries with no unblocked users.  This also assumes that the two meta keys are not repeated for a single user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation in the table `wp_usermeta` to get each `user` and `country` which meet your conditions:

```
SELECT user_id, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'user_country' THEN meta_value END) country
FROM wp_usermeta
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING country <> ''
   AND MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'user_blocked' THEN meta_value END) + 0 <> 1
```

and then join it to the table `wp_users`:

```
SELECT m.country, COUNT(*) total
FROM wp_users u 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT user_id, 
         MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'user_country' THEN meta_value END) country
  FROM wp_usermeta
  GROUP BY user_id
  HAVING country <> ''
     AND MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'user_blocked' THEN meta_value END) + 0 <> 1
) m ON m.user_id = u.ID
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(u.user_registered, '%Y-%m') = '2021-01'
GROUP BY m.country
ORDER BY total DESC
```